# File Permission - access denied

Tags: php, windows, file

I am making an application in php and i have to test certain directories(lets say "abc" folder) file permissions and i have to create a new file dynamically ,lets say "file" in directory "xyz" .. I want "abc" to be readable and writable by webserver(i.e. 666) and in order to be able to create file in directory "xyz" am checking it for readable and writable mode too(i.e. 666)... And here is what it prints
xyz directory - 777
abc directory - 777

But when i try to

```
$data = 'Some file data';
                        $fh = fopen($rootdir."\\file.php","r+");
                        if ( !fwrite($fh,$data))
                        {
                        //echo $rootdir;
                        echo 'Unable to write the file';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        echo 'File written!';
                        }
                        fclose($fh);
```

$rootdir contain address of folder "xyz" ... It shows following error

Message: fopen(C:\inetpub\wwwroot\file.php) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied

As i said C:\inetpub\wwwroot file permissions are 777.. And initially file.php don't exist but fopen will create it.. isn't it? And in case it won't, how can i create file dynamically?

Any help ?

Comment: How do you set octal permissions on a Windows FS?

Comment: These are the values i am getting from fileperms() ..

Comment: How did you set the file permissions?

Comment: I didn't set any file permissions.. its like i created these folders... and i checked there file permissions.. which is coming to be 777 in octal notation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$fh = fopen($rootdir."\\file.php","r+");;
```

will not create the file if it doesn't exist.
To create file you need to use

```
$fh = fopen($rootdir."\\file.php","w");
```

Or

```
$fh = fopen($rootdir."\\file.php","w+");
```

Refer to this [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

Comment: Hey thanks a ton !! But the first issue remains the same.. why fileperms() show 777 when it actually is not!

Comment: what is exact output of fileperms()

Answer (score 0):

Windows/NTFS uses an ACL for file permissions.

In the file property dialog box "security" tab, you need to give the user "Internet Guest Account ([something]/IUSR_[something])" write access, or full permission. You've done this?

- Right click on the file
- Click "Properties"
- Click the "Security" tab
- Find the user: "Internet Guest Account"
- Set the necessary permissions

If you want to IIS to be able to create files, you need to make sure you have these ACLs set up correctly on the *folder*.

Comment: NO actually issue is that why is it showing 777 permission than? Aftre giving Users full control, am able to write data in some existant file.. If file don't exist, it is showing this error:

Message: fopen(C:\inetpub\wwwroot/file.php) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: In case you didn't know, PHP was developed originally for *nix OSes (POSIX compliance etc). So it's not exactly 1 to 1 when it runs under Windows. Just as you notice with the DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. What OS are you using? Windows95? Can you verify that "Internet Guest Account" has "full control"?

Comment: Like I said, it's probably got to do with Linux/Windows. Rather than check for file permissions, you should check if the file is writeable, which is what you are doing.

Comment: is_writable returns the same result... even when permissions are not greater than 666.. it returns true.. :(

Comment: But when you try to write to the file, you get a failure. You are checking for that, in the above code. See this bug: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=27609